# Performance between 0-rtt and 1-rtt in TLS

Tags: security, ssl, https, tls1.2, rtti

I'm looking for a performance comparison between a connection TLS with 0-rtt and 1-rtt. In particular with the ClientKeyShare extension of TLS.
Is there a place where I can find these informations or a comparison?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you understand what RTT means? If yes then you should be able to compare the performance based on the latency inside a specific network setup. If not please consult [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-trip_delay_time).

Comment: Check [this](https://www.cambier.org/2017/03/15/introducing-zero-round-trip-time-resumption-0-rtt)